Suggested tag: rolling-your-own-crypto
How do you guys feel about introducing a rolling-your-own-crypto tag? We would then re-tag questions where the user is asking about homegrown crypto algorithms, homegrown crypto protocols, and/or homegrown implementations of known algorithms/protocols?
This could also possibly be dont-roll-your-own-crypto.

I don't think this is a good idea. A tag should be there for people searching a solution for their question, and I don't think anyone would search for rolling-your-own-crypto, other than maybe people who want to know what to downvote or close-vote (and I don't think this is a valid reason for such a tag).
Also, askers should at least theoretically be able to tag their own question with the right tags, and who would put a tag with the description "Don't do this!"? 
(This is similar to the homework tag, which has similar functions, and therefore is generally not used in Stack Exchange.)
Instead of putting such a tag to the question (which is an implicit way of saying to the asker "you are doing something wrong, please don't ask this here"), add a comment linking to a suitable other question, or an answer which explains why that is a bad idea (depending on how much you want to write and what actually was the question).

My thought is that this could be used for a comment linking to an example of why this is wrong. "Rolling your own is a bad idea. Here's a list of similar questions on this site where others have done similar things with predictably poor results." It would also likely be a suggested tag when a user goes to submit an applicable question. Regardless, yours is a fair criticism.

@StephenTouset, if you want a link to share with people to justify why not to roll your own crypto and what to do instead, here's one you can consider: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/2210/971  Feel free to improve that answer with some of the most notable examples of deployed systems that got broken because they violated this advice, if you think it would help people understand why they shouldn't roll their own crypto.
